# NullPointerException (Sharedpreferences)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I receive a NullPointerException error when starting my activity. My logcat says it is occurring in my activity but doesn’t specify where. I am trying to use SharedPreferences for the first time and don’t know where the error is occurring.

Here is my activity:

```
    public class SharedPrefLoginActivity extends Activity {


private Button cancelBttn;
private EditText rname;
private EditText rpwrd;
private Button rBttn;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private SharedPreferences dhj;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dhj = this.getSharedPreferences("DHJ", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    if(dhj.getString("password", null) !=null) {
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    rname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_uname);
    rpwrd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_pswd);
    rBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg_button);

    rBttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor dhjEditor = dhj.edit();
            dhjEditor.putString("rname", rname.getText().toString());
            dhjEditor.putString("rpwrd", rpwrd.getText().toString());
            dhjEditor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Credentials Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     }
      );
       }
    else { 

        Intent i = new Intent(SharedPrefLoginActivity.this, AccessApp.class);
        startActivity(i);   
    }
    cancelBttn.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Close application
            finish();
    }
    });     
    }}
```

logcat:

```
    09-14 09:27:26.244: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting  due to uncaught exception
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.SharedPreferences.Login/com.SharedPreferences.Login.SharedPrefLoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.SharedPreferences.Login.SharedPrefLoginActivity.onCreate(SharedPrefLoginActivity.java:58)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

Comment: As Sush said, it certainly does tell you where the exception occurs.                                          09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at com.SharedPreferences.Login.SharedPrefLoginActivity.onCreate(SharedPrefLoginActivity.java:58)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set the `cancelBttn` field:

```
 cancelBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button); // Insert your R.id.XXX here.
```

Also move

```
 setContentView(R.layout.register);
```

to right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. The `NullPointerException` occurs because the layout isn't inflated. You can see that in the last 4 lines of the stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. After applying the fix I still receive the same error. Could the error be somewhere else?

Comment: I updated my answer - you also need to move `setContentView(R.layout.register)` up.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this line is causing it:

```
cancelBttn.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
```

I don't see any instantiation for `cancelBttn` so it's null on this line...

Comment: added cancelBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button); but still receive the same error....?

Comment: So you're going to have to share what's in the line where the exception occurs.
Moving the setContentView upwards (as suggested by Nicholas) won't help you here, as you're not trying to access any layout element before setting the content view

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at     com.SharedPreferences.Login.SharedPrefLoginActivity.onCreate(SharedPrefLoginActivity.java:58)
09-14 09:27:26.293: E/AndroidRuntime(589):  at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

Let's you know that you're NullPointer is coming from the onCreate method. You must first instantiate your cancelButtn variable before you register it's listener. I wouldn't think it's an issue with the dhj member since it's not attached to a view, so the layout doesn't need to be inflated before it can be referenced..although it would be wise to set it's value after a call to setContentView().